# Response packets in Ionic BLE when writing

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, callback, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm currently trying to write something to a characteristic in Ionic BLE. I am expected to receive a response packet if the write is successful. However I do not know how to receive this packet. Whenever I write I am receiving a success callback, however I don't know where the packet would be found.

This is my code:

```js
   this.ble.write(id,service,
          characteristic,buffer).then(
            (data)=>{
              if(data!= null){
                this.setStatus(data)
              }else{
                this.setStatus("didn't work")
              }
```

In the success call back, the parameter passed in is a string that is 'OK'. Where do I go from here.

Answer (score 0):

The plugin you are using offers callbacks for the [write method](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#write) in case of success or failure.

One possible way of using them in your usecase could be:

```js
var success = function() {
    console.log("success");
};

var failure = function() {
    alert("failure");
};

this.ble.write(id, service, characteristic, buffer, success, failure)
```

Answer (score 0):

When your trying to write into the ble characteristics(write with response api) , you be responded with the acknowledgement . In case if you want the data in the response , you can go with notification api .**startNotification registers a callback that is called every time the value of a characteristic changes.**

> ble.startNotification(device_id, service_uuid, characteristic_uuid,
> success, failure);

You can refer [here](https://github.com/don/cordova-plugin-ble-central#write) for startNotification api with example.